# AWS FederatedSignin call doesn't return

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml

I have configured a SAML provider in AWS Cognito and I'm now trying to code the front end. I have a "Login with SSO" button on my front end, with this code:

```
 <button title="loginsso" onClick={() => this.handleSSOClick() } className='btn btn-secondary btn-xs buttonStyle'>
                 Login with SSO
                </button>
```

Calling this function:

```
    private async handleSSOClick() {
    
    console.log("SSO Clicked!");
    await this.props.authService.loginSSO();
}
```

which, in turn calls the loginSSO function here:

```
 public async loginSSO()
{
    try {
        console.log('Signing into azureadmaintel');
        const user = await Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'azureadmaintel' as any });
        console.log('SAML Federated Sign-In Successful:', user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('SAML Federated Sign-In Error:', error);
      }
      
}
```

Once it calls the federatedSignIn method it never returns, doesn't hit the console log or error message. Is it an async issue?

Comment: No, there's a lot of missing code here. See: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/advanced/q/platform/js/#subscribing-events